# Property encapsulation with property observer - Swift

Tags: swift, properties

I am trying to do property encapsulation with property observer. Refer below Sample Code. If `userName` is empty then need to set username as **Unknown**. I am checking this condition in `willSet` but unfortunately it unable to set the value  as `self.userName = "Unknown"`.

If I do same with `getter-setter`then it can be achievable with extra private param. Check Below code.

**With get-set**

```
private var userName : String
var name : String {
    get {
        return self.userName
    }

    set {
        if newValue.isEmpty {
            self.userName = "Unknown"
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample Code - WillSet**

```
class MyClass {
    var userName : String {
        willSet{
            print("Will set called")
            if newValue.isEmpty {
                print("If condi \(newValue) ..")
                self.userName = "Unknown"
            }
        }

        didSet {
            print("Did set called")
        }
    }
    init(name : String) {

        self.userName = name

    }
}


let c = MyClass(name: "Hello")
c.userName = ""
print("var ->", c.userName)
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Q:** How to achieve this encapsulation with willSet?? If I somewhere misconcepted then please correct me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reset in `didSet`:

```
class MyClass {
    var userName : String {
        didSet {
            if userName.isEmpty {
                self.userName = "Unknown"
            }
        }
    }

    init(name : String) {
        self.userName = name
    }
}
```

But keep in mind that property observers are not called from `init` so if someone does `let c = MyClass(name: "")` then `userName` will still be the empty string.

Comment: It is not working. Please [Check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xr2I.png). DidSet is called after the value is set, so you won't think we need to check condition in willSet ?? P.S. I added same condition in both willSet and DidSet same condition but still not working.

Comment: You are not using the code I posted. The code I posted does work.

Comment: OK we need to check param self not newValue or oldValue. I didnt observed that. Sorry my Mistake. Thanks . I wanted to know when to we have to check for newValue or OldValue and when we have to check for param self.

Comment: You can check `newValue` in `willSet` (but you can't change it). You can check `oldValue` in `didSet`. You use `self.property` to get the current value.